# How cast HWND to NSWindow * in FireBreath?

Tags: npapi, firebreath, browser-plugin

Is there any way to cast HWND FB::PluginWindowWin::getBrowserHWND  to NSWindow *? The reason why I need this, is to interact with Browser window, from my Cocoa app for OSX, (like open sheet on it,etc..). If there is no way, how else it can be done, any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `PluginWindowWin` is Windows specific. Furthermore, there is no (defined) access to windows for plugins on OS X.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no other way to open Cocoa app, on browser window?

Comment: @taxilian Is there something like PluginWindowWin for OSX? Can I draw something using  FireBreath  plugin on Browser in OSX? Or there is now way even get plugin window for OSX? I'm new at this, and don't have experience how it can be done. Thanks!

Comment: Let me state this very very clearly: There is no way to get the Browser NSWindow from a NPAPI plugin on Mac.

Comment: @taxilian Unfortunately.. I was trying to port something to OSX that was already done on Windows..and I'm using FireBreath it's AWESOME. Thanks!

Comment: If the answer is correct, please mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the NSWindow from a Mac NPAPI plugin. Back in the day of carbon it used to be possible to get some of them, but it was never a supported feature, just something that happened to work in some versions.

Sorry for the bad news

Comment: Thanks for a response. Is there any alternative way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean "alternative"? As he said, you *can't* do it. Pretty much all browsers now run NPAPI plugins in a different process, and it is *impossible* to get an NSWindow* in process A to a window that exists in process B. OS X simply doesn't work that way. It's not a Firebreath limitation, or even an NPAPI limitation, so you can't just work around it.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. With saying "alternative" I mean any workaround to open my Cocoa app as a sheet on Browser Window (modal), (on Windows version we were able to do that).

Comment: There is no sure way that I know of that you can find the browser window from a plugin.